# How to get the value of a QPropertyAnimation set on a widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function which set a `QPropertyAnimation` on a widget and the function can be called again before the animation has finished.

I'm trying to know if any possible previous call of the animation didn't finished yet, and in this case i could use the current value of the `frame_ani` animation as the `startValue`.

Isn't possible to get the animation set on the widget other than storing it somewhere?
I mean something like:

```
   QFrame* frame = new QFrame(this);
   frame->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100);
   QParallelAnimationGroup* animationGroup = new QParallelAnimationGroup();
   QVariantAnimation* frame_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(frame, "pos");
   frame_ani->setStartValue(QPoint(0,0));
   frame_ani->setEndValue(QPoint(300, 300));
   frame_ani->setDuration(9999);
   animationGroup->addAnimation(frame_ani);
   animationGroup->start();

   QTimer::singleShot(500, this, [=]() {
       // How to check if the frame has QPropertyAnimation set into it, and get its current value?
       QPropertyAnimation* ani =
           dynamic_cast<QPropertyAnimation*>(frame->property("pos").value<QAbstractAnimation*>()); // <- failed attempt

       auto ani_2 = qvariant_cast<QVariantAnimation*>(frame->property("pos")); // <- failed attempt
   });
```

The `singleShot` is just a workaround to illustrate the scenario, inside it  are some things I already tried to get the QPropertyAnimation and its value.

Comment: why not just use `frame->property("pos")` or `frame->property("pos").toPoint()`? You can use it directly as a start value in `setStartValue`.